# JavaFx: comboBox.setValue without ActionEvent

Tags: java, javafx

I have combobox with page numbers (1,2,3,etc). When user select the certain page (by mouse or by keyboard(as combobox editable)).I want to show and total pages. That's why on combobox action I also do:

```
combobox.setValue(currentPage+"/"+totalPages)
```

so the final code looks like

```
   @FXML
    private void onPageComboBoxAction(ActionEvent event){
       ....
       combobox.setValue(currentPage+"/"+totalPages)
    }
```

However this code fires one more ActionEvent and code cycles. So I see two possible ways:

1. Handle some specific events (but which and how?)
2. Find the way to change the value in combobox without firing one more event (again how?)

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: add the code to your question please.

Comment: @Tomek  Your solution is not I 'm looking for. As promttext is a promtext and value is value. You solution mix both of them. I mean your solution can work. But using it we can forget about advantage of promttext.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean here? I.e. is the total number of pages variable, or is it fixed? Are you really just wanting the display of the selected value to be different to the display in the dropdown? Is the `ComboBox` editable, or is the user only allowed to select from the dropdown?

Comment: @James_D This is one of many cases when I have such problem with comboboxes (setValue->ActionEvent->Cycle). The total pages is fixed and I could not to show it combobox value, for example to make a Label. However, it the simplest example I have imagined for describing of this problem. And the question is how to setValue and not to get in Cycle. Combobox is editable. Can we separate changing values by mouse, by keyboard and from code(setValue)? Did I make it clear?

Comment: The problem is you are confusing the model with the view. The data you are displaying is just the integer value. The view is the text you want to display. `setValue()` updates the model. You just want to specify how to display that value, not change it.

Comment: @James_D You mean I should write some "ValueFactory" for combobox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setValue(...)` changes the value that is held by the combo box (i.e. it changes the data, or the state of the underlying model). It seems to me that what you really want here is just to change the way the data is displayed. You change the display of the selected value by setting the button cell.

Here is an example in which the button cell keeps track of both the selected item and the number of pages:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PageNumberCombo extends Application {

    private static final Random RNG = new Random();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ComboBox<Integer> combo = new ComboBox<>();
        combo.setButtonCell(new ListCell<Integer>() {
            {
                itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> update());
                emptyProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> update());
                combo.getItems().addListener((Change<? extends Integer> c) -> update());
            }

            private void update() {
                if (isEmpty() || getItem() == null) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText(String.format("%d / %d", getItem().intValue(), combo.getItems().size()));
                }
            }
        });

        Button reloadButton = new Button("Reload");
        reloadButton.setOnAction(e -> reload(combo));

        reload(combo);

        HBox root = new HBox(10, combo, reloadButton);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(24));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 240, 60));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void reload(ComboBox<Integer> combo) {
        int numPages = RNG.nextInt(10) + 11 ;
        combo.getItems().clear();
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, numPages).forEach(combo.getItems()::add);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If your `ComboBox` is editable, then the button cell is by default a `TextField`, and the combo box's `converter` is used to convert the string value in the text field to the model value, and vice-versa. So in this case you just need to install a converter that converts between the integer `x` and the string `"x / total"`.

Note that by default this converter is also used to display the text in the cells in the drop down, so if you want these to appear just as the integer values, you need to install a `cellFactory` to explicitly create those cells.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class PageNumberCombo extends Application {

    private static final Random RNG = new Random();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ComboBox<Integer> combo = new ComboBox<>();

        combo.setEditable(true);
        combo.setConverter(new StringConverter<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Integer object) {
                return object + " / " + combo.getItems().size();
            }

            @Override
            public Integer fromString(String string) {
                int index = string.indexOf('/');
                if (index < 0) {
                     index = string.length();
                }
                String text = string.substring(0, index).trim();
                try {
                    return Integer.parseInt(text);
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    return 0 ;
                }
            }

        });

        combo.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null) ;
                } else {
                    setText(item.toString());
                }
            }
        });

        Button reloadButton = new Button("Reload");
        reloadButton.setOnAction(e -> reload(combo));

        reload(combo);

        HBox root = new HBox(10, combo, reloadButton);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(24));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 240, 60));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void reload(ComboBox<Integer> combo) {
        int numPages = RNG.nextInt(10) + 11 ;
        combo.getItems().clear();
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, numPages).forEach(combo.getItems()::add);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Uff! I thought I was getting crazy with your code :). Yes, this is what I need. However your code doesn't work if combobox is editable. Can it be solved?

Comment: Uh, yeah, you did say it was editable. I missed that. I think you can do it with a `StringConverter`, but I would have to figure it out.. I'll see if I have time to edit this later.

Comment: I tried StringConverter but as I understood it is used for all cells not only for buttonCell.

Comment: So, is it impossible to do?

Comment: No, use the `StringConverter` as I suggested. If you want the cells in the dropdown to be different, just use the usual `cellFactory`. See update.

Answer (score 2):

First remove all the listeners from the value property if any and add action event filter, e.g. by adding a method:

```
public class MyComboBox extends ComboBox<String> {
    public void setValueSilently(String value) {
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> filter = e -> e.consume();
        valueProperty().removeListener(myValueListener); // a custom listener
        addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, filter);
        setValue(value);
        removeEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, filter);
        valueProperty().addListener(myValueListener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use [prompt text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#setPromptText-java.lang.String-) instead setting value.

```
combobox.setPromptText(currentPage+"/"+totalPages);
```

but I don't know if it work once value is selected by user. Maybe you will have to `setValue(null)` just to see prompt text again. But then you would have to keep somewhere last selected value.